# POST fica vazio dependendo do site que uso

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Tenho um projeto em *Codeigniter* que fica em uma pasta dentro do domínio. A estrutura de pastas está da seguinte forma:

> /dominio/Web/projeto/

Chamarei de domínio e projeto devido ao nome do *cliente/site*

Consigo acessar o site de duas formas: *www.meudominio.com.br/projeto* ou *www.projeto.com.br*.

Porém, em todos os `forms` que faço, a variável `$_POST` fica vazia quando preencho pelo site *www.projeto.com.br* (o que deveria ser o correto pois o cliente deseja acessar como um site isolado de sua raiz). Se eu preencher os forms pelo site *www.meudominio.com.br/projeto* a variável `$_POST` recebe os dados normalmente e consigo prosseguir com a navegação.

Há alguma forma que eu possa fazer para que as duas URLs recebam o *POST* normalmente, como se fossem uma só?

Seguem os códigos do `form` e do controlador, para um `form` de login:

```
<form method="POST" action="sac/nova_conversa">
    <input type="hidden" name="lojaID" id="lojaID" value="<?= @$lojaID; ?>" />
        <p>
            <label>Nome:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Telefone:</label>
            <input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>E-mail:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
            <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="entrar" />
        </p>
        <?PHP if ($this->session->flashdata('errors')) { ?>
            <p class="erro"><?= $this->session->flashdata('errors'); ?></p>
        <?PHP } ?>
    </form>
```

Controller:

```
public function nova_conversa() {
    if ($_POST) {
        $data["nome"] = $this->input->post("nome");
        $data["telefone"] = $this->input->post("telefone");
        $data["email"] = $this->input->post("email");

        if (($data["nome"] == "") or ($data["telefone"] == "") or ($data["email"] == "")) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', 'Digite seus dados');
            redirect("sac");
        } else {
            $usuarioID = $this->sac_model->novo_usuario($data);

            $data["lojaID"] = $this->input->post("lojaID");
            $conversaID = $this->sac_model->nova_conversa($usuarioID, $data["lojaID"]);

            $this->session->set_userdata('chat_usuarioID', $usuarioID);
            $this->session->set_userdata('conversaID', $conversaID);

            redirect("sac/abrir_conversa");
        }
    }
}
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Para este tipo de situação, onde está `<b><input type="hidden" name="lojaID" id="lojaID" value="<?= @$lojaID; ?>" /></b>`, você deve utilizar assim `<?php echo @$lojaID; ?>`, aí o elemento será preenchido. Se inspecionar o código através do `F12` do Chrome irá ver que no método utilizado o valor está em branco, mas se utiliza o echo para imprimir o valor ele atribui ao html.

Comment: Assumindo Apache: podes adicionar o conteúdo do teu `.htaccess` que trata do _redirect_? Parece-me que estás a fazer um _redirect_ sem contemplar os valores do `$_POST`, por isso é que o formulário funciona numa localização mas não na outra.

Answer (score 1):

No arquivo `routes.php` altere esta linha:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "projeto";
```

No seu arquivo `config.php` coloque o seguinte:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Uso o seguinte `.htaccess` no diretório que está o meu `index.php`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Meu projeto está dessa maneira descrita acima, acredito que se alterar dessa forma irá funcionar do mesmo jeito que o meu funciona.

**Notei que a URL é case sensitive então se o nome da pasta do site estiver maiúsculo, na URL também deverá ser maiúsculo**

Se não houver duvida que toda esta configuração está correta então você pode verificar o seguinte, o `$route['default_controller'] = "projeto";` é uma configuração que define que ao acessar o seu site o primeiro controller que vai ser carregado é o `projeto.php` e o método chamado dentro dele será o `index`, se este estiver redirecionando para outro método então você também deverá repassar seus dados `$_POST` e `$_GET`

Resumindo...

```
www.meudominio.com.br -> default_controller/index -> default_controller/projeto
www.meudominio.com.br/projeto -> default_controller/projeto
```

**Essa provavelmente é a explicação para seu problema!**